# Apache: deny access to folder but allow with mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to prevent access to a folder `/workspace/test`

I've done this with the following piece of code

```
RewriteRule ^(workspace/test) / [R=404,L,NC]
```

Now I have a second rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^news\/(.*)$ workspace/test/news.php [L,NC]
```

The problem it that I get a `404` because of the first rewrite rule.

Is it possible deny access to files if the user enters it in the URL but allow access to these files if I do it with a `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /workspace/test [NC]
RewriteRule ^workspace/test - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ workspace/test/news.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: @rapre if the post helped mark it as an answer. The question won't appear in unanswered questions list.